# ViewBag, ViewData and TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Could any body explain, when to use

1. TempData
2. ViewBag
3. ViewData

I have a  requirement, where I need to set a value in a controller one, that controller will redirect to Controller Two and Controller Two will render the View.

I have tried to use ViewBag, the value gets lost by the time I reach Controller Two.

Can I know when to use and advantages or disadvantages?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) is a great post that explains the differences.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/17199709/2015869

Answer (score 310, accepted):

> 1)TempData

Allows you to store data that will survive for a redirect. Internally it uses the Session as backing store, after the redirect is made the data is automatically evicted. The pattern is the following:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // store something into the tempdata that will be available during a single redirect
    TempData["foo"] = "bar";

    // you should always redirect if you store something into TempData to
    // a controller action that will consume this data
    return RedirectToAction("bar");
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    var foo = TempData["foo"];
    ...
}
```

> 2)ViewBag, ViewData

Allows you to store data in a controller action that will be used in the corresponding view. This assumes that the action returns a view and doesn't redirect. Lives only during the current request.

The pattern is the following:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ViewBag.Foo = "bar";
    return View();
}
```

and in the view:

```
@ViewBag.Foo
```

or with ViewData:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ViewData["Foo"] = "bar";
    return View();
}
```

and in the view:

```
@ViewData["Foo"]
```

`ViewBag` is just a dynamic wrapper around `ViewData` and exists only in ASP.NET MVC 3.

This being said, none of those two constructs should ever be used. You should use view models and strongly typed views. So the correct pattern is the following:

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public Action Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { Foo = "bar" };
    return View(model);
}
```

Strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Model.Foo
```

---

After this brief introduction let's answer your question:

> My requirement is I want to set a value in a controller one, that
>   controller will redirect to ControllerTwo and Controller2 will render
>   the View.

```
public class OneController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["foo"] = "bar";
        return RedirectToAction("index", "two");
    }
}

public class TwoController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Foo = TempData["foo"] as string
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding view (`~/Views/Two/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)
```

---

There are drawbacks of using TempData as well: if the user hits F5 on the target page the data will be lost.

Personally I don't use TempData neither. It's because internally it uses Session and I disable session in my applications. I prefer a more RESTful way to achieve this. Which is: in the first controller action that performs the redirect store the object in your data store and user the generated unique id when redirecting. Then on the target action use this id to fetch back the initially stored object:

```
public class OneController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var id = Repository.SaveData("foo");
        return RedirectToAction("index", "two", new { id = id });
    }
}

public class TwoController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Foo = Repository.GetData(id)
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The view stays the same.

Comment: Thank you Darin for step by step. I got good understanding now. I have implemented your approach, which works great.

Comment: Great answer, but I disagree with the dogmatic statement "none of those two constructs should ever be used". I have found a couple legitimate usages for the ViewBag. For example, I set a `ViewBag.Title` property on all my Views which gets used in my `_Layout.cshtml` base view file. Another case where I use it is giving info-messages (e.g. "Product saved successfully!") to the users. I placed some generic markup in `Layout.cshtml` to render a message if provided and this allows me to set `ViewBag.Message` in any Action. Using a ViewModel property for either case has too many disadvantages.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Jesse, while this is an excellent description, blatantly stating there is no good reason to use ViewBag is a matter of a matter of opinion, no a matter of fact.

It is certainly a bad practice to overuse the ViewBag, and some developers fall into this trap, but tastefully used it is a powerful resource.

Comment: @ron.defreitas, alright, tell me then one good reason why would you use `ViewBag`. Please describe a specific, real world scenario, when ViewBag has some use. Since you are saying that it is, I quote *a powerful resource*, I guess you have some specific cases where this *powerful resource* is *powerful*. Since I've never used it in my career, I would be very happy to learn how people are using this *powerful* weapon.

Comment: We have an elitist over here. Darin, Jesse specifically mentioned one such example. Just because there are always other ways of doing things does not automatically negate their usefulness.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I have a scenario right now where I need to pass some information to the view from within an attribute method. Using filterContext.Controller.ViewData is substantially easier than trying to pass it to a strongly-typed view. That said, thank you for your explanation, it was very useful.

Comment: Great Answer. However I was briefly confused about the Session's baking store. I didn't realize TempData was cooking up foobars.

Answer (score 12):

### **TempData**

Basically it's like a DataReader, once read, data will be lost.

### **[Check this Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzrCK-mpXPY)**

### **Example**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        TempData["T"] = "T";
        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Test1");
    }

    public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        String str = TempData["T"]; //Output - T
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you pay attention to the above code, RedirectToAction has no impact over the TempData until TempData is read. So, once TempData is read, values will be lost.

### **How can i keep the TempData after reading?**

Check the output in Action Method Test 1 and Test 2

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        TempData["T"] = "T";
        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Test1");
    }

    public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        string Str = Convert.ToString(TempData["T"]);
        TempData.Keep(); // Keep TempData
        return RedirectToAction("Test2");
    }

    public ActionResult Test2()
    {
        string Str = Convert.ToString(TempData["T"]); //OutPut - T
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you pay attention to the above code, data is not lost after RedirectToAction as well as after Reading the Data and the reason is, We are using `TempData.Keep()`.  is that

### **In this way you can make it persist as long as you wish in other controllers also.**

### **ViewBag/ViewData**

The Data will persist to the corresponding View

Answer (score 3):

**ViewBag, ViewData, TempData and View State in MVC**

http://royalarun.blogspot.in/2013/08/viewbag-viewdata-tempdata-and-view.html

ASP.NET MVC offers us three options ViewData, VieBag and TempData for passing data from controller to view and in next request. ViewData and ViewBag are almost similar and TempData performs additional responsibility.

**Similarities between ViewBag & ViewData :**

> Helps to maintain data when you move from controller to view. Used to
>   pass data from controller to corresponding view. Short life means
>   value becomes null when redirection occurs. This is because their goal
>   is to provide a way to communicate between controllers and views. It’s
>   a communication mechanism within the server call.

**Difference between ViewBag & ViewData:**

> ViewData is a dictionary of objects that is derived from
>   ViewDataDictionary class and accessible using strings as keys. ViewBag
>   is a dynamic property that takes advantage of the new dynamic features
>   in C# 4.0. ViewData requires typecasting for complex data type and
>   check for null values to avoid error. ViewBag doesn’t require
>   typecasting for complex data type.

**ViewBag & ViewData Example:**

```
public ActionResult Index()

{  
    ViewBag.Name = "Arun Prakash";
    return View();    
}

public ActionResult Index()  
{
    ViewData["Name"] = "Arun Prakash";
    return View(); 
}
```

In View, we call like below:

```
@ViewBag.Name   
@ViewData["Name"]
```

**TempData:**

> Helps to maintain data when you move from one controller to other
>   controller or from one action to other action. In other words when you
>   redirect, “Tempdata” helps to maintain data between those redirects.
>   It internally uses session variables. TempData is meant to be a very
>   short-lived instance, and you should only use it during the current
>   and the subsequent requests only

The only scenario where using TempData will reliably work is when you are redirecting. This is because a redirect kills the current request (and sends HTTP status code 302 Object Moved to the client), then creates a new request on the server to serve the redirected view.

It requires typecasting for complex data type and check for null values to avoid error.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
   var model = new Review()  
   {  
      Body = "Start",  
      Rating=5  
   };  

    TempData["ModelName"] = model;    
    return RedirectToAction("About");   
} 

public ActionResult About()       
{  
    var model= TempData["ModelName"];  
    return View(model);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Keep()

Calling this method with in the current action ensures that all the items in TempData are not removed at the end of the current request.

    @model MyProject.Models.EmpModel;
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    var tempDataEmployeet = TempData["emp"] as Employee; //need typcasting
    TempData.Keep(); // retains all strings values
    } 

void Keep(string key)

Calling this method with in the current action ensures that specific item in TempData is not removed at the end of the current request.

    @model MyProject.Models.EmpModel;
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    var tempDataEmployeet = TempData["emp"] as Employee; //need typcasting
    TempData.Keep("emp"); // retains only "emp" string values
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

TempData 
will be always available until first read, once you read it its not available any more can be useful to pass quick message also to view that will be gone after first read.
ViewBag
Its more useful when passing quickly piece of data to the view, normally you should pass all data to the view through model , but there is cases when you model coming direct from class that is map into database like entity framework
in that case you don't what to change you model to pass a new piece of data, you can stick that into the viewbag 
ViewData is just indexed version of ViewBag and was used before MVC3

Answer (score 0):

Also the scope is different between viewbag and temptdata. viewbag is based on first view (not shared between action methods) but temptdata can be shared between an action method and just one another.