# ViewData not shown in Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have creatd a partial view and inside it I am using AJAx.BeginForm. In Post Edit Action Method, I am adding VIEWDATA Like this

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            service.SaveAccount(account);
            TempData["message"] = "Account has been updated successfully!";

            AccountInfo accountInfo = new AccountInfo();
            accountInfo.AccountStatuses = service.GetAccountStatuses();
            accountInfo.AccountTypes = service.GetAccountTypes();
            accountInfo.CreditTerms = service.GetCreditTerms();
            return View("DisputeSubscriber", accountInfo);

        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_UpdateAccountDetails", account);
        }
```

and redirecting to same partial view. In partial view, I have added like this:

```
 @if (TempData["message"] != null)
                    {
                        <div class="Message">
                           I am here.
                            @TempData["message"]
                        </div>
                    }
```

but this message is not shows. this message is also inside AJAX.BeginForm. Please suggest

Do I need to redirect main view instead of partial view or there is something I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using TempData and not ViewData which is [not quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata/7993283#7993283). Also you mentioned that you are using an `Ajax.BeginForm` to invoke this controller action. Since this is an AJAX call make sure that you have specified an `UpdateTargetId` in your AjaxOptions so that the resulting partial is injected somewhere into the DOM:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "foo" }))
{
    ...
}

<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I have used UpdateTargetId as well but it is not showing the div. I see that record is updated. I used alert and it shows error alert. "@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateAccountDetails", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "alert('done')", OnFailure = "alert('Error');" }))"

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, is the element updated after all when you used UpdateTargetId? I am not talking about the TempData issue. Put some dummy data in the partial and make sure it updates first.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to update targetid >? I just set updateTargetId to my div which i want to update

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, my answer has an example of that.

Comment: In your example, what value be set to foo div ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, the foo div is only a placeholder into which will be injected the result of the AJAX call : the partial.

Comment: will it be done automatically done ? In my case I have a partialview which onsuccess shows same partial view with success message or error message