# View text population using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view with some text that can be modified using the ViewBag

```
@(ViewBag.FooText ?? "foo")
```

I populate ViewBag.FooText in the parent view from a resource file:

```
@
{
    ViewBag.FooText = MyResources.Common.FooText
}
```

My question is whether this is the best place to populate this property (and all other text resources) or would the related controller, or somewhere else, be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using ViewBag if you can help it.  It is better to use a strongly-typed viewmodel object, bind the resources to that object (in the controller or in the object itself), and then push the viewmodel to the partial view.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` isn't the best place to "populate" any property or data.

It will be much better if you store it in the Model. **Model** View Controller...

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata/7993283#7993283) answer of @Darin Dimitrov, an MVC master over here...