# Remove TempData value when press Back in browser asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, tempdata

I have a little issue with MVC application.

I have an action which save information in database like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{
   // do something to save
   // save message in TempData
   TempData["Message"] = "Message";

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I show an alert message which shows if an item was saved or not. I'm doing in two steps.

1. in Site.Master

   ```
   <div id="message"><%=(TempData["Message"] as string)%></div>
   ```
2. in javascript

   ```
   if($("#message").text().length)
   {  
      alert $("#message").text(); 
   }
   ```

After saving item, I will be redirected to `Index` page and will display the alert box. That's fine.

The problem is the following: If I save item and redirected to `Index` and after that I press `backspace` key or click on `Back` button of browser, the alert still is shown.

What have I to do to destroy `TempData` value when going back using either backspace key or Back button of browser ? I don't want to display alert anymore in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Could you remove the value from TempData in the action which handles the page?

Comment: I did this, that's strange, that TempData is preserved somehow in last request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using ViewBag or ViewData.

Comment: And then ? will occur that alert again.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata