# ViewBag content not shown when page reload

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my project in mvc

i have controller to upload file in to a folder

```
   public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file == null) { ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file"); }
            else if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                .................
                else
                {   //Excel file copied temporarily to temp folder
                    var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/"), filename);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";

                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UploadSTR", "Upload");
    }
```

and my view is

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      File Path    put type="file"  name="file" id="file" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="btn" />
}
<p> Message:@ViewBag.Message</p>
```

my problem is that after submit, file is uploaded and the return to the same page  .But **ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully" is no shown in my view**

Answer (score 0):

If you use a view model, you can add the message as a hidden form value using the `Html.HiddenFor()` helper in your view.  This way the value would get posted back into the model on form submission.  You're probably not going to get the functionality you need using the `ViewBag`.

The `ViewBag` has certain uses where it is advantageous to use it, like for setting the page title in a layout.  But in general the `ViewBag` is a beginner level item that you should probably look towards abandoning in favour of view models, to make use of MVC's powerful automatic view model binding features.

Maybe have a run through the [MVC Music Store example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) or Google for other examples of using view models in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass data via ViewBag (and ViewData) during redirection, you need to avoid redirection or to use TempData. About TempData you can read here [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata) .

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag will not survive redirect. Use TempData instead.