# Hide Model Data in URL when Redirecting to another Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a model to action once the user logs in, but the whole model data is visible in the URL. How to hide those data from url??

Here is Sign in Code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //Input Validation.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                ViewBag.LoginState = "ERROR";
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "PlayerID  Password can not be empty.";
                return View("/views/home/SignIn.cshtml");
            }

            if (true == ((LoginAPIController)this.APIController).AuthenticateUser(email, password))
            {
                Account accountDetails = ((LoginAPIController)this.APIController).GetUserDetails(email);

                HedgeUtil.UserLoginToSession(accountDetails.emailAddress, accountDetails.firstName, accountDetails.lastName);
                return RedirectToAction("UserPortal", "Home", accountDetails);
            }               
          return View("/views/home/SignIn.cshtml"); 

        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.LoginState = "ERROR";
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Invalid UserId or Password, Please try again. Contact customer support if problem persists";
            return View("/views/home/SignIn.cshtml");
        }

    }
```

Notice `return RedirectToAction("UserPortal", "Home", accountDetails);` here accountDetails is model which is visible in url.

How to hide this data in url??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't necessarily agree with *vishal sharma's* answer. I'd like to explain further.

**HTTP is stateless.** This means that each request is treated like a new request, with the server having no inherent recollection of where this user has just been.

When you use `RedirectToAction`, you are redirecting the user somewhere and so they will make a new request to your server. You can't just "pass" a model to a redirect - the action that the user is in now and the action that they are going to are disconnected, separate.

The [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) method can only take an object describing route values.

One way to get around this is to use the `TempData`. While *TempData should be used rarely*, it is essentially a solution to this problem.

Put a model in the TempData and then redirect the user. You will have to extract the TempData on the other side to retrieve the model.

Further reading: [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data in TempData like this:

```
TempData["MyData"] = accountDetails;
```

and in that action:

```
public ActionResult UserPortal()
{
Account accountDetails = TempData["MyData"] as Account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC4 If you have observed RedirectToAction Method has 6 overload , 
one which here you have used is

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction
(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues);
```

to avoid parameters passed into url you have to use this overload

```
protected internal virtual RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction
(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

you can use routevaluedictionary like this

```
                Account accountDetails = 
                ((LoginAPIController)this.APIController).GetUserDetails(email);
                RouteValueDictionary rd = new RouteValueDictionary();
                rd.Add("accoundInfo",accountDetails);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", rd);
```

Comment: I tried the solution given by you its changing the url but the data inside the moderl becomes null :(

Comment: can you pls tell me older url and new url ?

Comment: new url looks like (http://localhost:22551/home/userportal?accountInfo=NameSpace.ModelName)