# Hold data for list to add later?

Tags: html, css, list, save

So no SQL tables or anything here. Basically, I have 3 pages that have 6 items each. Each item consists of an image and then some text and also a smaller image than changes from a check to an "x" depending on if user selects or not. So if the image is checked, the user is adding that to a list which would display on a fourth page. This data needs to persist through just a session and if the session times out, then it resets. If the list is complete and on that fourth page the user choices to email or share list via social sharing, then the data would be gone after that action. What I am trying to figure out is the best way to approach and implement this with minimal time and effort as it has to go out quickly. Can any of you explain and maybe point to some links with info on the best way to achieve?

This is being done in asp.net web forms with html, css, and javascript.

Much appreciated!

Comment: So store the data in the session? Except, of course, that sessions are often backed by a SQL database for durability.

Comment: Can always use localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag() (for view in razor) or ViewData[] (for page in .net) to hold data for one web page.when you want it to other page. You can pass it to other page.

check this out

[ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)