# Hide Url parameters in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to hide or encrypt mu Url Paremeter In MVC4 Web APPlication

My ACtion Code is

```
 public ActionResult Login(AllotteeModel model, string returnUrl)
        {


            var clogic = new CUserLogic();
            var cprop = new CUserProp();
            cprop.ConsumerId = model.Consumerid;
            cprop.Password = model.Password;
             var login = clogic.ValidateLogin(cprop);
            if (login=="0")
            {
                var data1 = clogic.Getallproperty(model.Consumerid);
                var data2 = data1.Single(e => e.ConsumerId == model.Consumerid);
                string username = null;
                if (data2.ConsumerId!=null)
                {
                    username = data2.ConsumerName;
                }

                Session["Key"] = model.Consumerid;
                Session["UserName"] = username;
                model.CustomerName = data2.ConsumerName;
                model.ConnectionNo = data2.ConnectionNo;
                model.Sibling = data2.Sibblings;
                model.ConnectionDate = data2.ConnectionDate;
                model.PhoneNo = data2.PhoneNo;
                model.PendingAmount = data2.Balance;
                model.EmailId = data2.EmailId;
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home",model);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
```

and URl After Login is

```
localhost:3192/Home/Home?Consumerid=TEST&Password=TEST&ZoneList=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]&CustomerName=ansf&ConnectionDate=06%2F14%2F1999 12%3A00%3A00 AM
```

Comment: why not POST the data ?

Comment: Use `POST` instead of `GET` on your login form

Comment: I have used   [HttpPost] Also on Login

Comment: any solutions Please...

Comment: after succesful login it goes to another controller how can i use post on that controller action!..

Comment: If you use Visual Studio you could actually use the project wizard to generate a working login/register example application.
Also if your goal is to encrypt the login details (and you should really) you need to make sure to use HTTPS on your production website.

Comment: Once a user has successfully logged in the login details shouldn't be needed anymore since a cookie would typically be used to identify the user in any subsequent requests.

Comment: Use `TempData` like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata) just before the GET `RedirectToAction`. In the redirected action get the value from `TempData` instead of via query string.

Comment: After login my URL LOOKS LIKE THIS IS THERE ANY PROCEDURE TO MAKE URL SIMPLE OR HIDDEN

Comment: you can make post request instead of get if parameters are large