# ViewBag not seen by view when view specified explicitly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am new to MVC (coming from Web Forms).  I have a controller with two actions like this:

```
Public Function Delete(ByVal id As Nullable(Of Integer)) As ActionResult
    Dim Count As Integer = IModel.DeleteMember(id)
    If Count = 1 Then
        ViewBag.Message = "Member " & id & " was deleted. "
    Else
        ViewBag.Message = "There was a problem deleting the record. "
    End If
    Return RedirectToAction("Members")
End Function
```

ViewBag is not passed to the Members view.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewBag` Allows you to store data in a controller action that will be used in the corresponding view. This assumes that the action returns a view and doesn't redirect. Lives only during the current request.

`TempData` Allows you to store data that will survive for a redirect. Internally it uses the Session as baking store, it's just that after the redirect is made the data is automatically evicted.

So you should use tempData

```
If Count = 1 Then
    TempData["Message"] = "Member " & id & " was deleted. "
Else
    TempData["Message"] = "There was a problem deleting the record. "

Return RedirectToAction("Members")
```

OR return a view, instead of redirect...

```
Dim Count As Integer = IModel.DeleteMember(id)
If Count = 1 Then
    ViewBag.Message = "Member " & id & " was deleted. "
Else
    ViewBag.Message = "There was a problem deleting the record. "
End If

Return View("Members")
```

refrence: [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will work:

```
Public static String msg
...
Public Function Delete(ByVal id As Nullable(Of Integer)) As ActionResult
    Dim Count As Integer = IModel.DeleteMember(id)
    If Count = 1 Then
        msg = "Member " & id & " was deleted. "
    Else
        msg = "There was a problem deleting the record. "
    End If
    Return RedirectToAction("Members")
End Function

Public Function Members() As ActionResult
    ViewBag.Message = msg;
    Return View()
End Function
```

Since you define the `ViewBag` variable and then `RedirectToAction`, the `ViewBag` value is lost and doesn't make it to the Members View.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It works and it uses `ViewBag`, as mentioned in the question