# How To Send Value in HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send an error message in  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

How should I do it?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home/ErrorPage("the error is from here")");       

public ActionResult ErrorPage(string error=")
{
     return View(error);
}
```

How should I show the error inside the view?

Comment: Where do you do error handling? Doing `Response.Redirect` is not the mvc-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. You would need a result which has a valid Url encoded query string:

```
"/Home/ErrorPage?error=the+error+is+from+here";
```

However, instead of direct construction, you should use [Html helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197(v=vs.118).aspx) to build the url, e.g.:

```
Url.Action("ErrorPage", "Home", new {error = "the error is from here"});
```

You can also use [TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata) to pass once-off information:

Note that as per @Vsevolod's comment, that you shouldn't use `Response.Redirect` directly. Use an MVC [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx) or `RedirectToAction` from your controller, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult MethodReportingError()
{
  TempData["Error"] = "Bad things happened";
  return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("ErrorPage", "Home"));
}

public ActionResult ErrorPage()
{
    return View(TempData["Error"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to pass Error. You are calling the information in url that is totally incorrect.

You can better pass information to error instead of url so it will make small and better url instead of blah blah in url.

Try to use `Httpcontext.Controllers.ViewData` to pass error to view and render the error there.