# Using tempdata as a error model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use TempData for user messages.

When I try to do this, it tells me TempData does not exist in the current context.

```
public class ServerMessage
{
    public void appendAlertMessage(string message, ServerMessageClass messageClass)
    {
        if(TempData["alertMessage"] == null) 
            TempData["alertMessage"] = message;
        else 
            TempData["alertMessage"] += "\n" + message;

        if(TempData["alertClass"] != ServerMessageClass.Error)
            TempData["alertClass"] = messageClass;

    }
}

public class ServerMessageClass
{
    public const string Success = "success";
    public const string Warning = "warning";
    public const string Error = "error";
}
```

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Inherit your class from Controller

Comment: I wrote it in Models.  I'd like to use it across my controllers.

Comment: Then pass TempData from your controller to the model

Comment: take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting a compilation error. `TempData` is a property of `ControllerBase`. So you cannot use it outside of a controller class.

Refer to this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx

From my understandings, it is OK to keep this checking inside the Controller. You can use a private method in the controller but that is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` only exists within the context of the Controller itself.

You may need to consider explicitly inheriting from the `Controller` class to expose it or consider building your message in your class setting the `TempData` to the value being returned (i.e. the message).

**Ignore The Following (It was just an idea, but isn't supported)**

If you are planning on editing it or making changes to it, you could consider passing it in as a reference via the [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword and updating it that way :

```
 // Calling the method (assumingly from your Controller)
 ServerMessage.AppendAlertMessage(string message, ServerMessage messageClass, ref TempData);
```

Then you should be able to access it within your method :

```
public void appendAlertMessage(string message, ServerMessageClass messageClass, ref TempDataDictionary tempData)
{
      // Update the TempData using tempData["foo"] = message, etc.
}
```

Comment: It's telling me "A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter"

Comment: It was just a thought, but that makes sense. Yeah, you'll probably need to just use your class to actually "build" your messages and then return them and set the `TempData` accordingly. Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly inherit from the `Controller`.