# Redirect IGrouping<string, model> List to another action in Same Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, razor, controller, igrouping

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { lst = finalData });
[HttpGet]
 Public ActionResult AcionName(IGrouping<string, ModelName> lst)
 {
  return View("ActionName", lst);
 }
```

i use this code to redirect my list to another action but this is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can we have a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You cannot pass complex objects like that using `RedirectToAction()`. Save the data, then pass just its ID to the GET method and get it again in the GET method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the `finalData` to a `Session` or `TempData` variable.

```
TempData["FinalData "] = finalData;
return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
```

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7993283/3082296): "`TempData` Allows you to store data that will survive for a redirect. Internally it uses the Session, it's just that after the redirect is made the data is automatically evicted"

Then in your `GET` Action Method,

```
Public ActionResult AcionName()
{
    var finalData = TempData["FinalData"] as IGrouping<string, ModelName>;
    return View("ActionName", finalData);
}
```

The problem is, if you were to refresh after the redirect, then `finalData` would be null. So, in that case you use `Session["FinalData"]` or get the data from the Database in your Get method again. You can go through the answer I have linked for disadvantages of using `TempData`.