# ViewData, ViewBag, TempData is server side state management technique or Client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net there are 2 types of State management technique

**Server Side State management**

1. Session
2. Application State
3. Profile

**Client Side state management**

1. ViewState
2. QueryString
3. Cookies
4. Control State
5. Hidden Fields

I know that in Asp.net MVC above all state supported except **ViewState** and **Control State**.

I'm confused over **ViewData, ViewBag, TempData** in which category they belongs like **Client Side State management technique** or **Server Side state management technique**.

I mean if we store data in **ViewData, ViewBag or TempData** then where they holds memory space at Client machine or Server machine.

Comment: All 3 are server side. Refer also [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Comment: Hi Stephen Muecke are you sure because i'm not getting any confident answer i have serched lot of article. I confused because reading this article  https://biswaranjan2010.wordpress.com/state-management-techniques-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Read the link gave you (or hundreds of others that explain what `ViewData`, `ViewBag` and `TempData` are). None of them have anything to do with client Side state management, and only `TempData` relates to server Side State management (it uses `Session`)

Answer (score 1):

ViewData, ViewBag and TempData are all stored on the server. Use TempData when you want to send something from one action to another action method.
Use ViewBag and ViewData when you want to send data from an Action method to a view.

Also the best approach is to simply use ViewModels