# .Net MVC ViewData, VIewBag, TempData

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, viewbag, viewdata, tempdata

Session variables use cookies to store the session id at the client-side and data is stored on server application memory with that session id.
I tried searching it but I did not get where does data of ViewData, ViewBag, Tempdata gets stored.
One of the Stack Overflow posts says they are a transient object, but it did not answer where they actually get stored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Comment: @KiranShahi, Thanks :) TempData uses Session internally. But not sure about ViewData and ViewBag.