# display message in every view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a website where the user can enter a message in a textbox, he can press submit and the text gets to a controller and there i put it in a viewbag. I want to display the message from the viewbag in every view but after refreshing the site, the viewbag gets empty.

Is there another way to display a message in every view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i need a way to display my message permanently, with TempData, ViewData and ViewBag the message vanished

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TempData.Peek(string key)`.

Put some message to `TempData`:

```
TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", "...");
```

Retrieve `message` in the View  using `Peek`:

```
@if (TempData.Peek("message") != null) {
  <div>@TempData.Peek("message")</div>
}
```

`Peek` returns an object that contains the element that is associated with the specified key, **without marking the key for deletion**. So if your refresh the page, the key remains in `TempData` - it will survive for multiple redirects.

`TempData` data is restricted to a single user’s session (so that users do not see each other’s TempData)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i needed!