# Accurate way of passing data controller to view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, to load some data to the view (combo boxes) I have been using `TempData`. I want to know if it is okay to use `TempData` for that purpose?

My current code is here; first I called data to a list in controller:

```
List<Request_Types> RequestTyleList = db.Request_Types.Where(r => r.Status == true).ToList();
List<SelectListItem> ReqTypeDropDown = RequestTyleList.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Text = r.Request_Type, Value = r.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
```

Then I am assigning this data to `TempData`:

```
TempData["RequestTyleList"] = ReqTypeDropDown;
```

In the view I called that temp data and assigning to the combo box

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    List<SelectListItem> ReqType = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("RequestTyleList");
}

-----------------

<div class="form-group row">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReqType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReqType, ReqTypes, "Select Request Type", new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReqType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

If I want to access those same data in Edit, I again create a list and putting data to the list and transfer to `TempData` and again call the same data from the view. Still I have 5 to 8 items of data on the list, I want to know when there are 100 items of data in `TempData`, will my system get slow? Are there any potential performance issues?

While surfing this on the internet, I got that same will do in the `Sessions`, but I don't know will it be suitable for this? Or else is there any good way to do this without dropping any performance of the system, like in one controller if I call and stores data, I can access those data from any view.

Comment: You can use `ViewData` instead of `TempData` for better performance if you do not need same data in subsequent request.

Comment: Please also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata for more details.

Comment: You can also create a `Model` class for this and use a strongly type helper.

Comment: @jishansiddique can you show me some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
@smc developments, please use below Model and html markup to show dropdown list for users
public class User
{
public int SelectedUserId{get;set;}
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedUserId, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "User"})
```