# Pass model between pages without multiple hidden fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing one wizard to user registration.

I already have page design and it's separeted in five views.

I want to pass data between all this pages and save them only in the last one.

How can I pass all model info between pages without add multiple hidden fields in each page(one hidden field for each field that is filled in previous pages)?

Comment: That's a broad question. What you're asking is how to maintain state. You can save state by putting data in a database but not saving a "final" version until it's all done. You can also store data in the browser's local storage.

Comment: These are Session, ViewState, QueryString, Cross Page Posting, etc. and these the objects that store the value and transfer it from one place to other place ViewData,ViewBag,TempData

Comment: details on ViewData, TempData & ViewBag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata